# Sum of Balanced Ternary strings

Tags: scheme, racket

I have to write a code that sums two strings of numbers written in balanced ternary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary).
Instead of using -1/0/+1, I have to use -/./+ 
Since I **cannot** convert the string-ternary-balanced numbers in integer-decimal numbers, **I have to manually sum the characters of the two strings in input**, but I have no idea how to deal with the carry generated by summing the various characters.

EDIT: This is what I've come up so far - https://pastebin.com/R98RDHTQ
However, if I sum - and --, the codes gives .++ instead of -++.
This is beacuse when it sums the partial result, .-+ , with the first carry, .-. it doesn't keep track of the second carry... How do I fix it?

```
(define btr-sum  
  (lambda(a b)

    (cond
      ((< (string-length a)(string-length b))(btr-sum (normalize a b) b))
      ((> (string-length a)(string-length b))(btr-sum a (normalize b a)))
      ((and(char=? (string-ref a 0) #\. )(char=?(string-ref b 0)#\b))(btr-sum (substring a 1 )(substring b 1)))
      (else (real (normalize(real a b ".") (create-rip a b ".")) (create-rip a b ".") "."));; (+(+ a b) c)
      )    
    )
  )



(define real ;;sums strings a and b without carry
  (lambda(a b r);;strings
     (if (>(string-length a)1)
         (string-append

          (real ;;recursive
           (substring a 0 (-(string-length a)1))
           (substring b 0 (- (string-length b)1))
           r)


          (string(somma ;;sums last chars of strings
                 (string-ref a (-(string-length a)1))
                 (string-ref b (-(string-length b)1))
                 )
                 )
          )

         (string(somma (string-ref a 0)(string-ref b 0)))
         )


    )
  )




(define normalize ;;if the length of subj < length of obj, normalize fills stacks up subj with "."
  (lambda(subj obj)
    (if (not(= (string-length subj)(string-length obj)))
        (normalize (string-append "." subj) obj)
        subj
        )
    )
  )

(define create-rip ;;generates the carry of the sum of a and b
  (lambda (a b c)
    (if (> (string-length a) 1)
        (cond ;; if length>1 then do it again
          (
           (and (char=? #\+(string-ref a (-(string-length a)1)))(char=? #\+ (string-ref b (-(string-length b)1))));;if +/+, add one + in carry
           (create-rip (substring a 0 (-(string-length a)1))(substring b 0 (-(string-length b)1))(string-append "+" c))
           )

          (
           (and (char=? #\-(string-ref a (-(string-length a)1)))(char=? #\- (string-ref b (-(string-length b)1))))if -/-, add one - in carry
           (create-rip (substring a 0 (-(string-length a)1))(substring b 0 (-(string-length b)1))(string-append "-" c))
           )
          (else  (create-rip (substring a 0 (-(string-length a)1))(substring b 0 (-(string-length b)1))(string-append "." c)))
          )

        (cond ;;if it's the last char do it only once
          (
           (and (char=? #\+(string-ref a (-(string-length a)1)))(char=? #\+ (string-ref b (-(string-length b)1))))
           (string-append "+" c)
           )

          (
           (and (char=? #\-(string-ref a (-(string-length a)1)))(char=? #\- (string-ref b (-(string-length b)1))))
           (string-append "-" c)
           )
          (else  (string-append "." c))
          )
        )
    )
  )


(define somma ;;general procedure to sum two char without taking care of carry
  (lambda(a b)
    (cond
      ((and (char=? a  #\-)(char=? b #\-))#\+)
      ((and (char=? a  #\.) (char=? b #\-))#\-)
      ((and (char=? a  #\+)(char=? b #\-))#\.)

      ((and (char=? a  #\-)(char=? b #\+))#\.)
      ((and (char=? a  #\.)(char=? b #\+))#\+)
      ((and (char=? a  #\+)(char=? b #\+))#\-)

      ((and (char=? a  #\-)(char=? b #\.))#\-)
      ((and (char=? a  #\.)(char=? b #\.))#\.)
      ((and (char=? a  #\+)(char=? b #\.)) #\+)
        )
    )
  )




(btr-sum "-""--")
```

Comment: Can you show us how far you've gotten, in order to illustrate the carry problem?

Comment: `(char=? (string-ref b 0) #\b)` looks like a bug.

Comment: This is probably much easier if you first convert to lists and then reverse the lists, so you can use "normal" list recursion and not have to sprinkle "refs" and "lengths" all over the place. `(first a)` is far more readable than `(string-ref a (-(string-length a)1))`. It's also more efficient to avoid those repeated length calculations.

Comment: I also thought of that but I forgot to say that I'm also not allowed to use lists

Answer (score 0):

Use `char->integer` and `integer->char` to convert back and forth between characters and integers.

Comment: This isn't the problem, I already have a procedure to sum two characters (without keeping track of the carry  sadly)

Answer (score 0):

Begin by working out a ternary plus table; the Wikipedia article you quoted gives the table about two-thirds of the way down:

```
       -1      0      1
     ----   ----   ----
-1   -1 1     -1      0
0      -1      0      1
1       0      1   1 -1
```

Then ternary addition is just the grade-school algorithm for adding two numbers, working right to left and carrying when necessary.

**EDIT:** The original poster asks how to keep track of the carry. I'm not going to write code, but you keep track of the carry the same way you do when adding two numbers by hand, in a temporary variable; call it `carry` and initialize it to zero. To add two numbers, work right to left using the following procedure: Add the two trits at the current position, using the ternary plus table shown above, then add `carry` to the result. The low-order trit of the result goes in the current position, and the high-order trit replaces `carry`. Be sure not to lose the final carry at the end.

Comment: But my problem is **how** do I keep track of the carry!